# scala cats ambiguous implicit values

Tags: scala, scala-cats, cats-effect

```
import cats._
import cats.implicits._

trait Console[F[_]]{
  def readInput() : F[Int]
  def print(msg: String) : F[Unit]
} 

class Foo {
  def doFoo[F[_]: Monad](number: Int)(implicit C: Console[F]) : F[Unit] = {
    C.readInput().flatMap{input => 
      if (input == number) C.print("you won").map(_ => ())
      else if (input > number) C.print("you guessed too high").flatMap(_ => doFoo(number))
      else C.print("you guessed too low").flatMap(_ => doFoo(number))
    }
  }
}
```

But I get this cryptic error from the compiler

```
cmd18.sc:5: ambiguous implicit values:
 both value catsStdInstancesForList in trait ListInstances of type => cats.Traverse[List] with cats.Alternative[List] with cats.Monad[List] with cats.CoflatMap[List]
 and value catsStdInstancesForVector in trait VectorInstances of type => cats.Traverse[Vector] with cats.Monad[Vector] with cats.Alternative[Vector] with cats.CoflatMap[Vector]
 match expected type cats.Monad[F]
else if (input > number) C.print("you guessed too high").flatMap(_ => dooFoo(number))
                                                                        ^
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem is that you're asking too much of Scala's type inference. It's trying to figure out the type parameter it needs for `doFoo[?](number)`, and while it's pretty clear to us as humans that it has to be `F` given the context the expression `doFoo(number)` appears in, the compiler isn't that smart.

The simplest solution is just to provide the type parameter explicitly:

```
.flatMap(_ => doFoo[F](number))
```

If you find that annoying, you can help the compiler out a bit by desugaring the `F[_]: Monad` constraint bound so that you can make the order of the `Console` and `Monad` instances explicit:

```
import cats._
import cats.implicits._

trait Console[F[_]]{
  def readInput() : F[Int]
  def print(msg: String) : F[Unit]
} 

class Foo {
  def doFoo[F[_]](number: Int)(implicit C: Console[F], F: Monad[F]) : F[Unit] = {
    C.readInput().flatMap{input => 
      if (input == number) C.print("you won").map(_ => ())
      else if (input > number) C.print("you guessed too high").flatMap(_ => doFoo(number))
      else C.print("you guessed too low").flatMap(_ => doFoo(number))
    }
  }
}
```

In your original version, the `Monad` context bound was getting desugared to an implicit `Monad[F]` parameter that came before `C: Console[F]` in the implicit parameter list, and so the compiler was trying to resolve it first. In the sugar-free version above I've reversed the order so that it will resolve the `Console[F]` first, which will make everything work out just fine when the compiler gets around to trying to infer `F` for the `doFoo(number)` calls.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I was also able to do `def play[F[_]: Random: Console: Monad]() : F[Unit] = {` which compiled fine without explicitly specifying F when calling doFoo.

Comment: Yep, that desugars to the same thing. My own preference would be to write out the arguments when the order matters, but that's a matter of taste.